# How can I commit/push changes to a "live" branch and then keep working on my "test/dev" branch?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, revert

I'm very new to working on larger projects and using any form of version control, so please bear with me.

I have a project running on a local/intranet webserver. I'm using `mercurial` for version control with `hgworkbench`/`turtoisehg` as a GUI. So far I've simply commited and pushed my changes to the repository into the `default` branch.

Now it's time to deploy the project to the live server for the first time. In order to run on the live server, I have to make a couple of changes to the project, mostly replacing connection strings, domain names, and links/references. After changing all this, I commit these changes to a new branch `deployment`. (Another person will take care of the actual deployment from there.)

Once I have pushed the modified files to the `deployment`branch I want my local files back to the last version of the `default`branch and continue to work from there (let's say the last ref# is 42, the push to the new branch is ref# 43; so i want my lokal system to have the status of #42 and #44 should then be the direct child of #42 in the default branch.)

How can I do this without somehow breaking any of the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the current branch:

```
hg branch
```

(From TortoiseHg Workbench, you see the current branch next to "* Working Directory *" at the top.)

To update the working directory to the `default` branch:

```
hg update default
```

(From TortoiseHg, use Repository --> Update...)

Now that you are in the `default` branch, you can commit your changes as you were doing before. Once you are ready for another deployment, you can merge the latest changes from `default` to `deployment`:

```
hg update deployment
hg merge default
hg commit
```

(From TortoiseHg, first update to the target branch, `deployment` in this case. Then right-click on the tip of the `default` branch and select "Merge with local..." And don't forget to commit the merge once you have reviewed it.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I think I got it.